# Undefined method `get' in Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm trying to create a functional test for my RESTful API with MiniTest:
    require 'test_helper'

```
class AutomaticTests < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "test1" do
    get '/'
  end
end
```

The code above triggers an error:

> Minitest::UnexpectedError: NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for

My test_helper.rb looks like this:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/rails"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  class << self
    alias :context :describe
  end
end
```

**How can I make 'get' method work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get comes from `rack/test`, so you will need to add that gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-test', group: :test
```

And then, in your test file or your `test_helper.rb`, add the following line:

```
require "rack/test"
```

... and ...

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods
end
```

You can also use the [`rack-minitest` gem](https://github.com/brandonweiss/rack-minitest).

Comment: Thanks, this error is gone, though I get a weirder error now: undefined local variable or method `app' for #<KlassTest:0x000000031080f8>

Given that I haven't my AutomaticTests class at all, it's simply "get '/'" without any "app" variables...

Comment: I think you might have to setup an "app" in your test_setup file. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of time to look into that right now, but I think you might salvage some information from this link: https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-rails-example/blob/master/test/test_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

You are inheriting from the wrong test class. Instead of ActiveSupport::TestCase you want to use ActiveDispatch::IntegrationTest.

```
class AutomaticTests < ActiveDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "test1" do
    get '/'
  end
end
```

See the [testing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) for more info on the test classes that rails provides.